# How to add regular expression to filter out the xhr URL in Cypress

Tags: javascript, regex, cypress

I have a scenario where in I have to process and validate the XHR response of nearly equal URLs:

```
URL-1: http://localhost:8080/api/customer/123/acounts
URL-2: http://localhost:8080/api/customer/asfgeras-qwe2-34hg-qwerhngfa
```

when I initialize the server in cypress and mention the xhr url as following, it always returns me the response of the URL-1 (which in my case is called first by the AUT) but I am unable to fetch the response of URL-2 although it is called in the AUT.

```
cy.server();
cy.route('GET','**/api/customer/**').as('GETCustomer);
```

I want to capture the response of URL-2.
Please suggest any approach to do so (preferably regEx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above solution works for a wild card search criteria but not for specific api search.
Using something like this can help you sort out the request

```
cy.route('GET', /\/api\/customer\/([a-zA-Z0-9]){8}-([a-zA-Z0-9]){4}-([a-zA-Z0-9]){4}-([a-zA-Z0-9]){4}-([a-zA-Z0-9]){1,}$/).as('GETCustomer');
```

Answer (score 1):

Cypress uses minimatch to filter URLs. Accordingly, you need to specify `**/customer/*`.

- `**` — feature known as globstar. Matches **all** files and zero or
  more directories and subdirectories. If followed by a /it matches
  only directories and subdirectories. To work that way it must be the
  only thing inside the path part e.g. /myapp/**.js will not work that
  way.
- `*` — Matches any string.

Source: https://globster.xyz/.

Full code:

```
cy.server();
cy.route('GET','**/api/customer/*').as('GETCustomer);
...
cy.wait('@GETCustomer')
  .then((response) => {
     <your handler here>
   });
```

[Check online here](https://globster.xyz/?q=**%2Fcustomer%2F*&f=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fapi%2Fcustomer%2F123%2Facounts%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fapi%2Fcustomer%2Fasfgeras-qwe2-34hg-qwerhngfa)

Answer (score 1):

> cy.server() and cy.route() are deprecated, see [link](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html#Syntax)

Use **cy.intercept()** instead, info [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept.html)

Example:

```
cy.intercept('GET', /api\/node1\/node2\/data$/).as('myAlias');
```

The second parameter above it's a random REGEX, but you can also pass a STRING.

then in order to wait for the async call you have to write:

```
cy.wait('@myAlias')
```